# search box - only first option works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a search box with an option to 'search catalog' and 'search site', which go to different urls. I can only get the 'search catalog' option to work. 'Search site' just goes to the same catalog url rather than to the homepage. I think there is an issue with the onchange, but I really don't know what I'm doing so I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
<!-- search -->
<div id="search">
    <a href="#" class="searchBtn"><span class="icon-search icon-white"></span></a>
    <div class="search">
        <form id="searchform" action="http://wilkinson.opac.marmot.org/Union/Search/" method="get">
            <select style="width: 150px;  background: none;" onchange="if(this.value == 1){jQuery('#searchform').attr('action','http://wilkinson.opac.marmot.org/Union/Search?searchsource=local/'); }else{ jQuery('#searchform').attr('action', '<?php echo home_url(); ?>'); }">
                <option value="1">Search Catalog</option>
                <option value="2">Search Site</option>
            </select>
            <input name="lookfor" maxlength="20" class="inputbox" type="text" size="20" value="<?php echo __( 'SEARCH ...', THEMENAME );?>" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='<?php echo __( 'SEARCH ...', THEMENAME );?>';" onfocus="if (this.value=='<?php echo __( 'SEARCH ...', THEMENAME );?>') this.value='';" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="go" class="icon-search"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end search -->
```

Comment: What does the javascript console show you?

Comment: What does `<?php echo home_url(); ?>` look like after the page loads (what is the html source code)?

Comment: @Robbert - Not sure about javascript console - the page is here www.telluridelibrary.org

Comment: @Sean - It goes to the homepage with ?lookfor after. So, a search for cat goes to www.telluridelibrary.org/?lookfor=cat

Comment: When I tested, the page works just fine. I selected Search Site and entered test and was taken to http://www.telluridelibrary.org/?lookfor=test.  Which is what your code says to do.

Comment: @Robbert - ok, i probably worded this wrong - but that ?lookfor=test doesn't actually return any search results. How can I change the code to have it actually search the site? (like I said, I really don't know what I'm doing here!)

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect code is working just fine, you just need to have a page that can actually return search results.  What I've done on other sites is to use Google's search api.  Since you're a public library, you can actually get them for free.  Take a look at Google's custom search: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/72325?hl=en